# Refreshing data in service

Tags: angular, rxjs6

The data in the API changes constantly. What is the best way to refresh data in Angular? [bitfinex.com API](https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:5m:tBTCUSD/hist?start=%7B$start%7D&end=%7B$end%7D&limit=1)

I have a service and component. In the service I download data using 'get'.

**service:**

```
getPrice(){

  return this.http.get('xxx');

}
```

**component:**

```
ngOnInit() {

   this.getPrices();

    setInterval(() => {
      this.getPrices();
    }, 5000);

  }

  getPrices(){
    this.tick.getPrice().subscribe(prices => {
      console.log(prices);
    });
  }
```

As you can see in the component I use 'setInterval' and refresh every 5 seconds.

I tried to refresh the data directly in the service.

```
return interval(5000).pipe(

      // ignore new term if same as previous term
      distinctUntilChanged(),

      // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
      switchMap(() => this.http.get('xxx')),
    );
```

But it shows data only after 5 seconds.

Comment: Can you use web sockets with your backend and frontend? Because maybe they're better than long polling for this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return interval(5000).pipe(

  // ignore new term if same as previous term
  distinctUntilChanged(),

  // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
  switchMap(() => this.http.get('xxx')),
);
```

The problem is in this block of code. `interval(5000)` will emit only once every 5 seconds, after the first 5 seconds. This is the behavior you observed.
You could use `timer(0,5000)` to get an observable that starts with 1 emit and then repeats every 5 seconds.

Also, i'm unsure what `distinctUntilChanged()` should do here. `interval(5000)` will emit an increasing number every 5 seconds, so the value will always be unique.

There also seems to be an extra comma after the `switchMap` you shouldn't need.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to recreate your issue in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8dxce), but I couldn't.

Could you try this and tell me what's wrong with it (apart from CORS which is server side and you can't do anything about)

Possibly your issue is related to this:
[image: API policy]

You can't poll the API every 5 seconds (you're DDOSing them :P), according to their policy. You can do ~10 requests per minute.

Try their [websocket api](https://bitfinex.readme.io/v2/docs/ws-general) that streams data to you when it changes, without the need to poll from the client (the server will send you new data as it becomes available, you just need to handle it).

Comment: *apart from CORS which is server side and you can't do anything about* well thats more client dependent then server to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

1) This will run in the background if you dont destroy your eventlisteners on redirect / page-leave.

I would suggest implementing a destructor-function.

```
deregisterListeners() {
    this.eventListeners.forEach(listener => {
        listener();
    });
    _.remove(this.eventListeners); //this is lodash,  it loops through all instances of w/e you're looping through
    clearInterval(this.intervalFunc);
}
```

Then add your eventlisteners like this in ngOnInit

```
this.eventListeners.push(this.$scope.$on("$destroy", this.deregisterListeners.bind(this)));
this.intervalFunc = setInterval(() => {
     // your code / function that calls the data here
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

They block as you set the refresh every 3 seconds. 5 seconds is optimal, tested: D

First, I wanted to learn without websockets, hence my question how to do it best.

Comment: Answers are not meant for adding information to your question. You should edit the original question or add a comment to it. You probably cannot comment yet so you should edit the OP.